# AngularJS directive modify loaded template in link or compile function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm loading a template inside my directive and I'd like to modify it based on some given attributes. How can I do that ?

Here is my directive :

```
directives.directive("myDirective", function($http, $compile){
    return {

    restrict: 'E',

    scope : {
    },

    templateUrl: 'lib/directives/myTemplate.html',

    link : function(scope, element, attrs) {

        // I need template to contain myTemplate.html code, how can I do that ?
        var trThead = template.find("thead").find("tr");

        var headers = scope.attrs["headers"];
        for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            trThead.append('<th><span class="th-sort">' + headers[i] + '</span></th>');
        }

        element.append(template);



    }
  };
});
```

I don't want to define the HTML code directly in my directive since it's too big.

Comment: You can always load another template, compile it, append where needed.

Comment: I tried with `var template = $compile('lib/directives/ing-table-page.html')` but the argument is not valid. Is it what you mean ?

Comment: Yes. But you first want to download template using `$http.get(templateUrl).then(function(template) { $compile(angular.element(template))(scope).appendTo(somewhere) })`. Something like this I think.

Comment: Use the `compile` phase of your directive, see the compile section at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile for some more information. There you can modify your DOM.

Comment: I guess, what you're looking for is, to use `element` instead of `template` in this line: `var trThead = template.find("thead").find("tr");`

Comment: @naeramarth7 yes indeed, I had missed something, thank you !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As answered by naeramarth7, the template set in the *template* or *templateUrl* parameters can be accessed using the element parameter of the link/compile method :

```
compile : function(element, attrs) {

}

link : function(scope, element, attrs) {

}
```